# Gesture recognizer issues

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around gesture recognizers. I want to target a subview. Here's an example that works with the main view:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: hex_pin_view!, action: #selector(openEmojis(sender:)))
gesture.delegate = self
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Here's the subview target, this dose not work and is what I'm looking for:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: hex_pin_view!.add_emoji_img_view, action: #selector(openEmojis(sender:)))
gesture.delegate = self
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

I'm getting a crash error:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Tho the selector is the same, I don't get it.

Anyone have a clue what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: The selector method must exist on the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `target` of a gesture recogniser is the object that will receive messages from the gesture recogniser. or simply put, the object that holds the function that will handle the message.

Alot of the time the target: is set to self.

`selector` is the function/method that will handle the messages.

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openEmojis(sender:)))
gesture.delegate = self
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

So there, the currrent class/object should have a method called `openEmojis`. The gesture is added to the mapView here

```
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

So when the map gets tapped, your function should be called.

If you want the gesture to trigger when your subview is tapped. instead add the gesture recogniser to the subview instead:

```
add_emoji_img_view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I tried adding the gesture recognizer to the subview without luck. Forgot to mention the main view is in a UIView class that is added as subview to MKAnnotationView.

Comment: MKAnnotationView has its own gesture recognisers on it already i believe

Comment: I'm getting the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView openEmojisWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: you would need to show the code for openEmojisWithSender

Comment: solved it!! the annotation view's frame was not covering the button.